# A way to talk about complex analysis without parameterizations

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question

In the way that we got rid of the rieman integral for most purposes (not including complex analysis) with the lesbeague integral, which is much more "clean", is there a way to get rid of parameterizations in complex analysis? I know that the integrals there are independent of it, as is rieman integral via rieman sums.

Another motivation for this, is that it feels "ungeneral" to have to deal with domains that have a boundery is pathwise smooth, wouldn't it be much better if could talk complex analysis on arbitary open connected sets?

Comment: Contour integrals are unique up to path homotopy, does that answer your question?

Comment: @Mathematician42 That is true, but not exactly, I was hoping for a definition that avoids the need to parametrize. Something like I give you a set of points in the plane and a fucntion, and you give it a number, and if it turns out to be parametersizable that is the integral with the parametrization.

Comment: Could you draw a diagram explaining what you mean? That would be a great way to attract attention to the question